# Document digital signature in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, document, digital-signature

a new legislation forces my application to allow users attach only digitally signed documents. I have never treat digitally signed documents in any special way in my apps before so I have no clue which approach to choose.

Basically there are two different approaches I can use.

1. Implement a functionality which allows users to sign documents
2. Let users to sign documents using other software and only check whether the document contains signature and verify its content

My application is written in Zend framework and supports uploading of pdf, doc/docx and xsl/xslx documents

I'd like to know how can I find out whether the document contains digital signature + timestamp and what's in it (name, company) or whether it is valid or not so I can allow/refuse its uploading.

Or I'd like to know what should I do to allow users digitally sign documents and add a timestamp to a signature in my web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can add digital signatures to Word (docx) documents with the help of [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/digital-signature-docx-pdf#digital-signature-DOCX).

It does not need Microsoft Office and works on any server that runs PHP.

You may also use the same package to sign PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

All of mentioned formats support embedded digital signature, but I have serious doubts that you will find PHP library to handle these formats for verification of whether the signature is included.

To let users sign documents you need to have the document on the client side OR support distributed signing. From your description I guess that documents are already stored on the client system, so all you need to add is something that performs signing on the client computer.

I can imagine Java applet which will sign the document from within browser when users choose the data, and will then post the signed file to the server. This is what most banking browser-based software does.

I know one library for Java that can do digital signing of PDF and office documents. It's our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-security.php) (Java edition). You can build a browser applet using our components. For PDF signing there also exists iText, but I don't know anything about Office DOC and XLS files signing in Java.